# Search in cell and delete (formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following formula `=LEFT(G2,SEARCH("""",G2)-1)` on a cell that contains the following data `4.8" (306ppi) HD Super AMOLED touchscreen` so that it returns only the the number (4.8).

It works, however, not all strings will have a quotes after the number, some contains a dash `5.2-inch full HD (424ppi) IPS touchscreen` and therefore i get an error on those cells `#VALUE!`.

I thought I could just edit the formula and add the dash in the criterion; `=LEFT(G2,SEARCH(""",-",G2)-1)` but it doesn't work, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=LEFT(G2,IFERROR(SEARCH("""",G2),SEARCH("-",G2))-1)
```

If `G2` doesn't contains both `"` and `-`, you can use next formula to return error message

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(G2,IFERROR(SEARCH("""",G2),SEARCH("-",G2))-1),"quote and dash not found")
```

Comment: How about if I want to use it on a cell that is being fetched from another workbook () something like `(=devices!K2(=LEFT(G2,IFERROR(SEARCH("""",G2),SEARCH("-",G2))-1))`

Comment: change `G2` to `devices!K2` like this: `=LEFT(devices!K2,IFERROR(SEARCH("""",devices!K2),SEARCH("-",devices!K2))-1)`